# HTML Parser validate tags

Tags: c#, html, html-parser

I need html parse which have capability to identify error in generated html and if tags are not closed then close it and return the valid html.

More detail: i am getting data from database and break that record to show partial detail on my website to click on more button then show complete content. After breaking string then validate.

I have already used Html Agility Pack but i am new to use it, if this library solve my issue then guide me how (tutorial) or suggest me another library.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such a library does exist. The problem is, that some libraries can indeed identify errors in your HTML but they cant fix them for you.

I think using the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) as a service is the best starting point here. There's an open source library which uses the API of the W3C validator to validate a document and gives you the response if it is valid or not as well as errors and warnings. I would start with this and then go on from there.

- [W3C Markup Validator library in C#](http://sourceforge.net/projects/w3cmarkupvalida/)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of validation programs from the World Wide Web Consortium, the W3C:

Windows: http://validator.w3.org/docs/install_win.html

UNIX / Linux: http://validator.w3.org/docs/install.html

You can also use their web services to validate your [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), [HTML](http://validator.w3.org/source/), [XML](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/webdata/xsv), [XHTML](http://validator.w3.org/), [JavaScript](http://validator.w3.org/) and many other web technologies. The [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) is one of the overseers of keeping the Internet highly interoperable and internet devices somewhat compatible with each other.

Comment: read question again, I have added more details to better understanding

Comment: Try HTML::Tidy, there are online and locally deployed options for it. If I were to have to clean up tags, I'd simply run my markup through Perl and HTML::Tidy to quickly clean up my markup. Search Yahoo, Bing or Google for it. Sorry, I'm just not a Google evangelist, I spread the love!